# .net 6 how can I get Configuration before the app is build

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-6.0

I am changing my project from .net 5 to .net 6 and have experienced an issue in the program.cs file with the current error of

**Cannot modify ServiceCollection after application is built**

I am needing to read the configuration before the app is built but the only current way that I know of getting the configuration is after the app is built . This is part of my code:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);


// Add builder.Services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddCors();

var app = builder.Build();

IConfiguration configuration = app.Configuration;

var appSettings = new AppSettings(configuration);
var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(appSettings.Secret);
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(x => // error happens here we have already used builder.Build()
{
    x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
            .AddJwtBearer(x =>
            {
                x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                x.SaveToken = true;
                x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidateAudience = true,
                    ValidAudience = appSettings.Target,
                    ValidIssuer = appSettings.Target
                };
            });
```

Is there a way of getting **IConfiguration** before we call **builder.Build()** ? Since I need the configuration to pass into the class AppSettings which then gets a secret key and allows me to do Authentication on JWT token .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

move `var app = builder.Build()` after authentication configuration.

the `.Build()` method essentially takes your configuration and gives you a `WebApplication` that's built upon the `WebApplicationBuilder` so you cannot modify the `app` after it's been built

Comment: perfect thanks a lot, that is exactly what I needed to do .

Comment: But the question was how to get configuration before Build...

Comment: That's not useful in all the cases. For example, I'd like to retrieve the configuration, run database migration and then set up repositories services BUT i can't build the application until repositories and services are built,.

Answer (score 1):

Since the "accepted answer" is a workaround that doesn't address the actual question, you can access Configuration using the WebApplication builder if you need it prior to the app being built:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var myConfigSetting = builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("MyKeyName");
```